# Material Letter Icons for PHP

Tags: php, image, icons

I know that this is a generally broad question but I have been looking all afternoon and have yet to find a php library that works for my needs.
 What I want is a simple class that I can pass in a Name or Character and it'll generate one of those Material Like design Letter Icons with a random colour in the background. 
 I would prefer the icon in png or jpeg format.

Something like this just for php would be perfect https://github.com/eladnava/material-letter-icons

[Material Icon from js Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdN68.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use html, css for a span. Use an array of colors in PHP and then choose one color from it randomly. CSS can make a span look like a circle. Add extra css as per your like.

```
<?php
function letterIcon($char) {
   $colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'];

   $color = $colors[rand(0, count($colors) - 1)];

   return "<span style=\"background-color:{$color}; border-radius: 50%; height:200px; width:200px; padding:20px;\">{$char}</span>";
}
echo letterIcon('A');
?>
```

Comment: I would do this but I am looking for a image to display instead of regular html

Comment: @aaron thanks for the comment. I have edited it. Please upvote.